# DOJO 'TypeError:Cannot read property 'style' of null' error response while sending xhrPost request

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

I am using DOJO framework to submit form details to server. xhrPost method is used to submit the form to server.JSON message format is used.

When this works in most desktop browsers and some mobile browsers, I am getting  error

```
TypeError:Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

consistently with some mobile devices.

Pl help.

Comment: Can you post some code that fails and a stack trace if possible?  If you have this with mobile devices, specify which.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the dojo code in:

```
dojo.ready(function(){
    ...
});
```